# Github token access for latest release

Tags: github

is there a way to give a GitHub token only access to pull the latest release from my private GitHub repository. for updating a electron application. I don't want the token to have access to anything else but the latest release only

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Tokens are generally scoped much more broadly than that (usually to your entire account), and even for ones that are scoped more narrowly, they'd cover at least all of the releases for the repository, if not the rest of the repository contents as well.

If you're trying to distribute software that's in a private repository, you should use some sort of CDN or cloud bucket for doing that (over HTTPS) and implement a suitable digital signature scheme to prevent rogue updates.